# Issues sending requests using fetch

Tags: laravel, fetch, ngrok

I am using FETCH to make GET requests. I am also using NGROK for HTTP tunneling. My problem is here when I use `var url = 'http://localhost:9090/test-message'`, I get a response but when I use 
`https://c2f2493e.ngrok.io/test-message` I don't get a response. I don't know what the problem might be here.

Here is the full code:

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: The URL is not sending any response? It's empty if you open it in your browser.

Comment: Could it be a CORS issue? Are you getting any errors in your console?
https://ngrok.com/docs#cors-basic-auth

Comment: @maio290 when I open on a browser, it works.

Comment: @fyroc no errors on the console.

Comment: The url does not have any GET method request

Answer (score -1):

This url  `var url = 'http://localhost:9090/test-message '` does not have any Get Method request.
You May try Like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "http://localhost:9090/test-message";
    var res = str.split("/");
    res = res.reverse();
    alert(res[0]); //text-message
}
```